# How to create new folder each time I run script

Tags: python, opencv

I have a script that creates a sequence of pictures each time is ran. 
What I want to do is to create a new folder each time the script runs, so each sequence of pictures is stored in the new folder. 
Can somebody tell me how to do it?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create a new folder and give it a new name every time your script is run.
You could append your folder name with a DateTime stamp, or any other logic that suits your needs.

script.py

```
import os
import time

def create_images(folder_name):
    # Create and store your images in folder_name
    pass

if __name__ = "__main__":
    folder_name = 'my_folder_' + time.strftime("%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S")
    os.mkdir(folder_name)
    create_images(folder_name)
```

Comment: That's nice. How would I have to do to get the folders a numerical sequence rather than a timestamp. For example, 0001, 0002, and so on?

Comment: use glob to get a list of all the folders in the directories split on _ for each folder name and get the number (i.e 001, 002) convert to integer and sort and take the last. up the number by 1 and use that to create your folder name.

Alternatively, you can look at the create time of the folders and get the most recently created folder

Answer (score 1):

If you want to name the folders with a numerical sequence rather than a timestamp, you can do it like this:

```
import os
folder_names = filter(os.path.isdir, os.listdir(os.getcwd()))
last_number = max([int(name) for name in folder_names if name.isnumeric()])
new_name = str(last_number + 1).zpad(4)
os.mkdir(new_name)
```

This finds the largest number that already exists as a folder, then adds one to that number and zero pads it to 4 characters long, and creates a new folder with that name.

Comment: your script gives me an odd error: 
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '.gconf'

Comment: That's because my answer was assuming that all the folder names are valid integers, which is a bad idea. I've edited my answer to add the condition `name.isnumeric()` so it should work now.